# Create a constructor for an outer class with inner classes that have constructors?

Tags: apex, constructor

What would a constructor for the outer class of the following look like?

```
public class outerClass {

    public Data data {get;set;}

    public class Attributes {
        public String symbol {get;set;} 
        public String name {get;set;} 
        public String displayName {get;set;} 
        public String systemEmail {get;set;} 

        public Attributes(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4){
            symbol = s1;
            name = s2;
            displayName = s3;
            systemEmail = s4;
        }
    }
    public class Data {
        public String type_Z {get;set;}
        public Attributes attributes {get;set;} 

        public Data(String s1, Attributes att){
            type_Z = s1;
            attributes = att;  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're asking about how you'd populate the `data` property of class `outerClass`.

In the end, a constructor for your `outerClass` class really won't be any different than any other constructor you might write. You're probably just out-thinking yourself here.

You have 3-ish options here:

- Follow the dependency injection principle, and have the client of `outerClass` provide the `Data` and `Attributes` instances required to construct your object
- Take parameters that allow you to construct the `Data` and `Attributes` instances that you need
- Just create an instance of `Data` and `Attributes` in the constructor for `outerClass` (and take no parameters)
- Don't worry about creating `Data` and `Attributes` in your constructor, and provide methods to set/get one (or both) instead

I, myself, would prefer the first approach (DI via constructor), the constructor for that might look like this:

```
public OuterClass(Data d){
    this.data = d;
}
```

and you'd end up using that like this:

```
OuterClass.Attribute myAttribute = new OuterClass.Attribute('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
OuterClass.Data myData = new OuterClass.Data('A string', myAttribute);

OuterClass myOuterClass = new OuterClass(myData);
```